# How do you escape a dollar sign in gettext .po file?

Tags: gettext

This is the first question I've asked here, so please be kind...

In my PO file, I have a localized string that contains a dollar sign. I have not been able to escape the dollar sign (to avoid gettext's attempt at dollar-substitution) with the desired results. An example PO entry to clarify what I'm trying to do:

`msgid "myStringId"`
`msgstr "My string that contains a $ sign"`

gettext throws up on the $ in the msgtr. I've tried escaping using the following approaches:

`msgstr "My string that contains a \$ sign"`
`msgstr "My string that contains a $$ sign"`
`msgstr "My string that contains a '$' sign"`

...without success. The third approach (single quotes) gets the closest, but returns the dollar sign *and* the single quotes.

returned => `My string that contains a '$' sign`
desired => `My string that contains a $ sign`

My question again: How do you escape dollar signs in gettext PO entries?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried, but how about using C's octal escaping `\044` or the unicode one `\u0024`?

Comment: I have the same question about escaping a dollar sign ($) a gettext .po file, and I don't understand what you're suggesting to do here.  Would you mind explaining? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I found out that I could just replace my $ with its HTML entity code. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10225521/470749 For $5, I now write `&#36;5`