# Printing " with gettext

Tags: escaping, gettext

I want to output the translation of this string

`By clicking on "Post"`

Using gettext, how do I escape the quotation mark? Should I try `\ "`?

```
msgid "By clicking on"
msgstr ""
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you need to escape double quotes with a backslash (\").

The [gettext manual](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html#PO-Files) says the following:

> The two strings, untranslated and translated, are quoted in various ways in the PO file, using " delimiters and \ escapes
>
> ...
>
> Each of *untranslated-string* and *translated-string* respects the C syntax for a character string, including the surrounding quotes and embedded [backslashed escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences).

Comment: Thank you Jörn. In this case the text is going to render as HTML so I could use the HTML escape sequence for `"`